# How to communicate between two embedded devices over ethernet?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am not expert on this subject, need your suggestions. I have a few devices on ethernet/LAN. I wanted to have these devices communicate over LAN without going into their network configurations. Below is my plan, please let me know if this can be achievable:

1) I install TCP/IP stack on these devices

2) I give them their hostnames like device1, device 2 etc....

3) I configure these devices for local-link networking, so that they can configure themselves and get their IPs.

4) I use socket programming and access each device by using hostnames.

Please let me know if this can be done without much hassle, and let me know if I have missed out something in above mentioned points.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a good approach.

If your embedded devices have a good IPv6 stack, I recommend using it instead of IPv4. link local addresses work better with IPv6. Most IPv4 stacks are configured to try to obtain an address from a DHCP server first, and only fall back to link local addresses if they can't get one. The link local address and DHCP address might be mutually exclusive, so the link local address doesn't become operational until after DHCP has been tried and timed out. The link local address might even be disrupted if DHCP periodically retries. Although the devices will normally be connected to each other and there won't be a DHCP server, you don't want to disable DHCP, because the devices probably *should* obtain a DHCP address if they are ever connected to a wider network. With IPv6 on the other hand, the link local addresses come up immediately when the interface comes up, and stay up continuously while other IP addresses (from autoconf or from DHCPv6) may come and go.

Link local addresses alone won't let the devices contact each other by hostname, but dns-sd (mDNS, zeroconf) will. If you are using Linux then you can use avahi as a dns-sd stack.

Better than using hostnames, consider having the devices probe for each other by dns-sd service type. If you are using a custom protocol between your devices, make up a unique service tpe name and have the devices advertise themselves it and probe for it with dns-sd.

Comment: Thanks, this was really useful. I will get back to you once I get some more knowledge of dns-sd.